# How to remove (anonymise) all links in dom

Tags: html, dom, hyperlink, href

Is there any way how to remove (anonymise - just place some empty string instead of url) all links in document?

A tags, and some javascripts actions which can open new url.

I have html in document and I am using nodejs, I can use puppeteer or some dom tool.

Comment: Yes there is. Sounds like you already have some ideas on what tools to use, but it also sounds like you haven't tried it out. I'd say get started, and if you run into problems ask a more specific question.

Comment: I dont know which elements should I remove to anonymize all those options. I know that I need to remove a href, but are there any other elements which can containes some clicable url??

Comment: `a` is the main one in static HTML. If you're dealing with Javascript almost anything is possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can do this:

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var anchor of anchors) {
anchor.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
}

I've read that 'javascript:void(0)' is the best substitute.